# glFramebufferTexture2D with cube map textures

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3, fbo, render-to-texture

I am trying to use render to texture concept with cube map textures but somehow texture is not getting applied to geometry in draw call. Here is my code

```
#define WIDTH 64
#define HEIGHT 64
glGenTextures(1, &id1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, id1);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &Fboid);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


glTexImage2D(types[i], 0, GL_RGBA,WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);


}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Fboid);


    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)                      
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,types[i],id1,0);


draw_cube();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

draw();
```

I have verified that framebuffer binding is complete or not. Also draw_cube() correctly draws geometry as per expected. When i remove FBO and supply data to glteximage2D() it correctly applies cubemap texture to geometry in draw() call. Width height is same as the viewport set in draw_cube call.

What's wrong with above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what excactly belongs into the body of your `for` loop (hint: correct formatting of your question would have helped). But nevertheless, the way it is currently written doesn't make much sense at all.

If it is only the single line after the `for` statement (as it currently seems), then you're binding all the cube faces to the same color attachment and thus only the last call (`types[5]`) will prevail, which seems strange. If you intend to bind all six faces at once (and thus make `draw_cube` render to all six faces in one go using multiple render targets), then you should use `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i` instead of just `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. But in this case, depending on your hardware/driver, 6 might be quite high (so to say: too high) a number of active multiple render targets.

But maybe the `draw_cube` call also belongs into the `for`-loop (thus rendering the six faces individually). In this case you should put it into the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,types[i],id1,0);
    draw_cube();
}
```

**EDIT:** As *Nicol Bolas* points out in his comment, you might also use layered rendering and bind the whole cube map as render target, using the geometry shader output variable `gl_Layer` to determine the cube map face into which a primitive should go.

In this case you would just have a single call to

```
//note: just ...Texture, without ...2D!
glFramebufferTexture(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, id1, 0);
```

Comment: He may also be trying to do [layered rendering](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images).

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, didn't consider that. I guess in this case he would just use `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` as target?

Comment: He would have to use `glFramebufferTexture` as well as that target.

Comment: @NicolBolas Forget what I said, it seems `glFramebufferTexture` doesn't take texture target.

Comment: Sorry for poor formating of code, actually there is single line in `for` loop i.e. `glFramebufferTexture2D` call. I am not trying layered rendering as @Nicol has pointed out. Is it possible to bind all six faces at once and make a `draw_cube` call to serve the purpose? Can you provide me psuedocode for the same?

Comment: @Roshan: And what would that *mean* to render to 6 faces at once?

Comment: Problem solved. As @ChristianRau pointed out, i shifted `draw_cube` call in `for` loop so that it will attach to each face of the cube instead of only `types[5]` in previous code.. Thanks a lot guys..